# What are some common software design patterns, when it comes to raspberry pi programming?

Tags: python, sensor, software-recommendation

I am kind of confused when I see raspberry pi code for reading sensor inputs, opening lights e.t.c.

I am not experienced with python, but I would expect that code is much like in ui programming.

E.g. Events fired by sensors, buttons, timers, or async operation completions (sometimes debounced/throttled) which cause event handlers to be executed.

Instead I always see examples using **infinite while/for loops inside which all the sensor values are checked, and the outputs are controlled**, which seems confusingly simplistic (but again I don't have experience with python so I could be wrong).

I would like to know whether there are some software design patterns for programming in raspberry pi, which are not part of the 101-guides.

Comment: This is a very open ended question, and not really the place to be asked. Please see the help section with regards to what questions are acceptable. The answer really is "It depends" because depending on what type of sensors, how they communicate with the pi(i2c,uart,spi, ect) and what the requirements are as far as how fast they need to be processed, what else is running on the pi. What processing/storing is done with the data.

Comment: Most people aren't going further than copypasting all the wrong patterns they saw somewhere on SE – sad, but true.

Answer (score 2):

Patterns used on a given platform are conditioned by its userbase. Most novice users will find the concept of a loop much easier to understand than the concept of events, let alone multithreading.

Typical UI applications are based on the same kind of infinite loops processing incoming data. The only difference is that the loop itself doesn't belong to the application code, instead, you define call-back functions which are called under certain conditions constituting an "event".

You could write a loop querying 5 sensors and add the desired logic directly in that loop, or you could write a loop querying an arbitrary number of sensors and allows registering callbacks like `OnSensor1Data()`, then put your logic in the callbacks. Arguably, the seconds solution is more elegant, but somewhat more difficult to write.

Comment: After all, the Raspberry Pi is meant to be *educational*, so one has to expect a lot of *novice coding*.